# The "header" in the LinkedList class in Java API

Tags: java, linked-list

In reading the LinkedList doc, I am a little puzzled by the uses of "header". Normally, the header is the first node in a linkedList. But here it looks like the 'header' is a dummy node in the list and it points to the first and last nodes of the list, thus making the LinkedList a circular one. Is that true?

```
private transient Entry<E> header = new Entry<E>(null, null, null);
public LinkedList() {
    header.next = header.previous = header;
}

public E getFirst() {
    if (size==0)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    return header.next.element;
}

public E getLast()  {
    if (size==0)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    return header.previous.element;
}

public E removeFirst() {
    return remove(header.next);
}
```

Comment: Yes. The Java API's LinkedList implementation.

Comment: I don't know. I see that from Java 1.4. Josh Bloch coded it.

Answer (score 3):

> But here it looks like the 'header' is a dummy node in the list and it points to the first and last nodes of the list

That much is true

> thus making the LinkedList a circular one.

That's not exactly true: structurally, the list is indeed circular, because the header "loops" it around. That is only an implementation detail, a common trick that lets you avoid declaring two things (`header` and `tailPiece`) instead of one. The fact that the same entry is used for both ends by itself is insufficient to make the list circular: there is no way for you to loop around the last node "from the outside", because the `count` prevents you from doing so.

Comment: But if I just follow the 'next/previous' links, will I be able to loop through the list? Do I have to use count to loop through?

Comment: @user697911 Correct, if you simply follow the prior/next links, you'll loop around. However, if you ignore the count, you would go through the dummy `header` element, which carries no data. For example, if you decide to go through a three-element list `{A,B,C}` in a circle, you'll see `A, B, C, null, A, B, C, null, A, ...` and so on.

Comment: So, this should be the best way to implement a doubly linked list in general?

Comment: @user697911 Well, there's no "best" way in general: every language has its own specific way. However, this one is pretty darn good, as it lets you avoid some of the ending condition checks.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. `header` stores references to both the head and tail of the list. This helps in reducing cost of operations involving delete/add/view for both the ends of the list.

With the availability of references to both the ends, operations like `getFirst`, `getLast`, `removeFirst`, `removeLast`, `addFirst`, `addLast` etc. don't require list traversal.

Comment: The header doesn't store any object. Right?

Comment: No it is instantiated as `new Entry<E>(null, null, null);`. Only the `next` and `previous` references are assigned values when the `LinkedList` constructor is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

A circular list is a cheap way to avoid storing both head and tail pointers in the top-level structure.  I don't know about Java's `LinkedList` implementation, but this is certainly a trick pulled in e.g. the GCC implementation of `std::list`.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `LinkedList` is using what's called s *sentinel* node. They've chosen to use one sentinel for both head and tail; other implmentations will use two separate sentinels.

In either case, the use of sentinels allow the rest of the implementation code to not deal with the null case. For example, consider adding a node. Without a sentinel:

```
Node newNode = ...;
if (header == null) {
  header = newNode;
  tail = newNode;
} else {
  newNode.previous = tail;
  tail.next = newNode;
  tail = newNode;
}
```

With the sentinel:

```
Node newNode = ...;
newNode.previous = sentinel.previous;
newNode.next = sentinel;
sentinel.previous = newNode;
```

Here's the [Wikipedia article on Sentinel Nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node).